# Using SSAS to predict likelihood of user performing X action

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas

This is my first foray into SSAS, so apologies up front.  I'm not sure I know enough about the technology to even ask the question correctly, at this point.

I have a relational database that I need to predict which types of users are most likely to take a certain kind of action.   E.g. what user types are most likely to perform user_action_id = X

My anonymized structure:

[image: My anonymized structure]

A 'type' can be looked at as a combination of values from lookup tables.

So, UserA and UserB might look like this and be considered the same 'type' of user:

```
===================================================================================
|user_name | user_id | country_id | business_units_id | business_group_id | etc..
===================================================================================
| UserA   | 1        | 1          | 3                 | 12                | etc
| UserB   | 2        | 1          | 3                 | 12                | etc
===================================================================================
```

Whereas UserC would be a different 'type' of user due to the different business_units_id:

```
===================================================================================
|user_name | user_id | country_id | business_units_id | business_group_id | etc..
===================================================================================
| UserC   | 3        | 1          | 4                 | 12                | etc
===================================================================================
```

After watching demos, it seems like this should be very easy, but the demos are all using the AdventureWorksDW database (which is dimensional), and I’m coming from a relational db.  I've tried a LOT of approaches to this based on demos/articles/documentation, and thought about listing them, but I feel like they’re so far off the mark that it would just waste space.

I think I've included all relevant information, but like I said, I’m not familiar enough with the technology to know.

Update:  I'm including my current MDX query, in case that helps (*vUserDimension* is my view containing all user-describing data.  This is how we  know what 'type' of user it is.):

```
SELECT
[User Actions].[User Action Id],
PredictProbability([User Actions].[User Action Id],2),
t.[business_group_name],
t.[country_name],
t.[job_family_name],
t.[job_function_code_name],
t.[org_chart_name],
t.[org_unit_name],
t.[user_name],
t.[user_name]
From
[User Actions]
PREDICTION JOIN
OPENQUERY([My Dev],
'SELECT
[business_group_name],
[country_name],
[job_family_name],
[job_function_name],
[org_chart_name],
[org_unit_name],
[user_name],
[user_id]
FROM
[dbo].[vUserDimension]
') AS t
ON
[User Actions].[User Id] = t.[user_id]
```

Comment: You can create a denormalized view to use as a fact table for an SSAS database.  Each of your lookup tables would be dimensions in SSAS.  You could either make UserAction a dimension, or create a different measure for each possible action.   Either way that would let you see how each dimension affects the counts of each action being taken.

Comment: @TabAlleman - Thanks for your reply.  I thought a denormalized view would be two, or more tables, whereas my fact table is singular.  It would make sense to me to make a view that includes my fact table, and the lookup tables, but just a view of the fact table by itself (as a view) doesn't make sense to me.  My current attempt has dimensions for each lookup table, and the entire structure represented in the DSV.  I've taken several approaches at creating the cube against this, but I can't figure out how to pull the correct data back.

I'll create the UserAction measure like you suggested.

Comment: I was referring to denormalizing your "users" table.   From your diagram, I didn't know if you had one row per user, or one row per user-FK.  It looks like your vUserDimension view is what I had in mind though.  I've never heard of Prediction Joins, it looks like they are DMX, which I've never used.   Your query above doesn't look like any MDX query that I've ever seen.   As far as creating your cube, I would add a FK column for ActionType and a measure column for ActionCount to your vUserDimension and base your measure group on that view.

Comment: Have you checked out [SSAS Data Mining](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc510301.aspx)?